# Counting latest instance of multiple only based on filter context

Tags: ssas, powerbi, dax, powerpivot, excel-2016

I've got a large table of events that have occurred in an inventory of vehicles, which affect whether they are in service or out of service. I would like to create a measure that would be able to count the number of vehicles in the various inventories at any point in time, based on the events in this table.

This table is pulled from a SQL database into an Excel 2016 sheet, and I'm using PowerPivot to try to come up with the DAX measure.

Here is some example data `event_list`:

```
vehicle_id    event_date    event         event_sequence    inventory
100           2018-01-01    purchase      1                 in-service
101           2018-01-01    purchase      1                 in-service
102           2018-02-04    purchase      1                 in-service
100           2018-02-07    maintenance   2                 out-of-service
101           2018-02-14    damage        2                 out-of-service
101           2018-02-18    repaired      3                 in-service
100           2018-03-15    repaired      3                 in-service
102           2018-05-01    damage        2                 out-of-service
103           2018-06-03    purchase      1                 in-service
```

I'd like to be able to create a pivot table in Excel (or use CUBE functions, etc) to get an output table like this:

```
date          in-service     out-of-service
2018-02-04    3              0
2018-02-14    1              2
2018-03-15    3              0
2018-06-03    3              1
```

Essentially, I want to be able to calculate the inventory based on any date in time. The example only has a few dates, but hopefully provides enough of a picture.

I've basically come up with this so far, but it counts more vehicles than desired - I can't figure out how to only take the latest event_sequence or event_date and use that to count the inventory.

```
cumulative_vehicles_at_date:=CALCULATE(
    COUNTA([vehicle_id]),
    IF(IF(HASONEVALUE (event_list[event_date]), VALUES (event_list[event_date]))>=event_list[event_date],event_list[event_date])
)
```

I tried using MAX() and EARLIER() functions, but they don't seem to work.

Edit: Added the PowerBI tag as I'm now using that software to attempt to solve this as well. See comments on Alexis Olson's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a much cleaner method than I gave previously.

---

Let's add two columns onto the `event_list` table. One which counts vehicles `"in-service"` on that date and one which counts vehicles `"out-of-service"` on that date.

```
InService = 
    VAR Summary = SUMMARIZE(
                      FILTER(event_list,
                          event_list[event_date] <= EARLIER(event_list[event_date])),
                      event_list[vehicle_id],
                      "MaxSeq", MAX(event_list[event_sequence]))

    VAR Filtered = FILTER(event_list,
                       event_list[event_sequence] =
                           MAXX(
                               FILTER(Summary,
                                   event_list[vehicle_id] = EARLIER(event_list[vehicle_id])),
                               [MaxSeq]))

    RETURN SUMX(Filtered, 1 * (event_list[inventory] = "in-service"))
```

You can create an analogous calculated column for `OutOfService` or you can just take the total minus the `InService` count.

```
OutOfService =
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT(event_list[vehicle_id]),
        FILTER(event_list,
            event_list[event_date] <= EARLIER(event_list[event_date])))
    - event_list[InService]
```

[image: Data Table]

Now all you have to do is put `event_date` on the matrix visual rows section and add the `InService` and `OutOfService` columns to the values section (use Maximum or Minimum for the aggregation option rather than Sum).

[image: Output]

---

Here's the logic behind the calculated column `InService`:

We first create a `Summary` table which calculates the maximal `event_sequence` value for each vehicle. (We filter the `event_date` to only consider dates up to the current one we are working with.)

Now that we know what the last `event_sequence` value is for each vehicle, we use that to filter the entire table down to just the rows that correspond to those vehicles and sequence values. The filter goes through the table row by row and checks to see if the sequence value matches the one we calculated in the `Summary` table. Note that when we filter the `Summary` table to just the vehicle we are currently working with, we only get a single row. I'm just using `MAXX` to extract the `[MaxSeq]` value. (It's kind of like using `LOOKUPVALUE`, but you can't use that on a variable.)

Now that we've filtered the table just to the most recent events for each vehicle, all we need to do is count how many of them are `"in-service"`. I used a `SUMX` here where the `1*(True/False)` coerces the boolean value to return `1` or `0`.

Comment: Thanks for this! It looks like a better solution. I'm still having some performance issues for my particular data set, but this appears to be a solution so I'm going to mark it as such.

Comment: Yeah, it's going to be resource intensive on a large set because each row has to check all of the rows with earlier dates, but that's necessary because of the way the data is recorded. Restructuring the data before pulling it into Power BI would probably be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty difficult. I don't have a great answer, but here's something that kind of works.

You'll create a new calculated table where you'll calculate the status for each vehicle on each date. Start with the base cross join for each vehicle and each date:

```
= CROSSJOIN(VALUES(event_list[vehicle_id]), VALUES(event_list[event_date]))
```

Then add a calculated column to find the max sequence number for each vehicle on that date.

```
Sequence = MAXX(
               FILTER(event_list,
                   event_list[event_date] <= Cross[event_date] &&
                   event_list[vehicle_id] = Cross[vehicle_id]),
               event_list[event_sequence])
```

Now you can lookup the inventory value for each vehicle/sequence pair with another calculated column:

```
Inventory = LOOKUPVALUE(
                event_list[inventory],
                event_list[vehicle_id], Cross[vehicle_id],
                event_list[event_sequence], Cross[Sequence])
```

The result should look something like this:

[image: Cross Table]

Once you have this, you can create a matrix using this calculated table. Put the `event_date` on the rows and `Inventory` on the columns. Filter out blank inventory values in the visual level filter and put the `vehicle_id` in the values field, using a count or distinct count as the aggregation method (instead of the default sum).

It should look like this:

[image: Result]

Comment: The output looks exactly right! I've been using only Excel and PowerPivot for this task. Looks like I may be hitting the limitations of that tool. 

Your pictures are from PowerBI? I'll see if I can get that running. Haven't really used it before. 

Thank you!


(I've tried to upvote your answer, but I don't have enough reputation yet!)

Comment: Power Pivot should be able to do this as well. I'm just more accustomed to working in Power BI (it's a bit less clunky) and I forgot you didn't have that tag. The DAX is nearly the same for both.

Comment: I don't appear to be able to create a Calculated Table as your initial instruction shows to do in PowerPivot. If the option is there, I haven't yet found it. However, I managed to get a copy of PowerBI and have been moving the data over there and working on implementing your suggestion.

Comment: I'm trying to implement this, however I'm running into resource issues. The actual event_list table has about 250,000+ rows in it with up to 13 sequences per ID. This results in the cross table being about a half a billion rows, and PowerBI starts throwing memory errors on the sequence calculated column. While this seems to be a solution, do you have any suggestions for something a bit less resource intensive? We are pulling the table through a SQL query on a Microsoft SQL Server and have access to SSAS services as well, if that helps with pointing me in a better direction.

Comment: Yeah, the cross join approach is going to be terrible on large datasets. I'll try to find a more efficient approach, but I may not have time as this is not an easy problem. I know a cleaner solution is possible, but I haven't quite nailed it down yet.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it! I'll keep working in PowerBI, maybe some of the other DAX functions that didn't work in PowerPivot would be available (SELECTEDVALUE, TREATAS, etc) and may help.