# Percent Retention

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a "Percent Retention" for policies during a given time period ( By month, YTD and year over year) .  So all of the policies at a given time period compared to those active at the end of the period.

Policies can be:

```
    N=New
    RN=ReNew
    C=Cancel
    RI=ReInstate
    NR=NonRenew
```

Transaction data kinda looks like this, the StatusNum is something I can derive to show inforce status.

```
PolicyID PolicyNum StatusDate Status StatusNum Net 
1        123       1/1/2018   N         1      1
2        123       3/31/2018  C         0      -1
3        123       4/1/2018   RI        1      +1
4        123       6/1/2018   RN        1      0
5        222       2/1/2018   N         1      1
6        222       7/1/2018   RN        1      0
7        333       1/1/2018   N         1      1
8        333       6/1/2018   NR        0     -1
9        444       1/1/2018   N         1      1
10       444       5/30/2018  C         0     -1
```

My best guess on how to do this is to take the sum of the last StatusNum values at a PIT (partitioned by Policy Number) divided by the first StatusNum value at the beginning PIT. So if I filter by dates 1/1/2018 to 8/1/2018

- 123 will be in force (+1,+1)
- 222 will not be in force yet(so not counted for anything) (+0,+0)
- 333 was in force at the beginning, but it non renewed (+1,-1)
- 444 was in force at the beginning, but it cancelled (+1,-1)

So 3 of the policies were active at 1/1/2018 and 2 cancelled, 1 doesn't matter so the retention would be 33.3%

Can anyone offer feedback if this is the best way to do this and how to accomplish this?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

**Update**

This is kinda what I am looking for, but it is too slow:

'AsOfPolicies = 
var A= SELECTCOLUMNS(SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(Transactions[PolicyNumber], filter( Transactions,Transactions[DateKey]=min(Transactions[DateKey])&&Transactions[IsInForce]=-1)   ),"aPolicyNumber", [PolicyNumber])
var B=SELECTCOLUMNS(SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(Transactions[PolicyNumber], filter( Transactions,Transactions[DateKey]<=MAX(Transactions[DateKey]) ),"MaxDate",MAX(Transactions[DateKey]) ),"bPolicyNumber",[PolicyNumber],"MaxDate",[MaxDate]) var C = SELECTCOLUMNS(filter(CROSSJOIN(A,B),[aPolicyNumber]=[bPolicyNumber]),"cPolicyNumber",[aPolicyNumber],"MaxDateKey",[MaxDate]) 
Var D = SELECTCOLUMNS(filter(CROSSJOIN(C,Transactions),[cPolicyNumber]=[PolicyNumber] && [MaxDateKey]=[DateKey]),"PolicyNumber",[PolicyNumber],"PD_ID",[PD_ID],"IsInForce",[IsInForce]) 
Return D'

**Update**

Also the filter does not appear to be working

Comment: Why is 222 not in force yet? 8/1/2018 is certainly after 2/1/2018 and 7/1/2018.

Comment: This question reminds me of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51315009/counting-latest-instance-of-multiple-only-based-on-filter-context/). You may be able to use similar logic.

Comment: 222 is not in force on 1/1/2018, therefore it would not be counted in the numerator or denominator.  Only policies in force on 1/1/2018.  Great find for the other solution!  I'll see if I can get it working and report back. Thanks!

Comment: I wrote the other solution, so it was in the back of my mind. I'm still not positive I'm following the logic completely. The 33% retention is for policies started by 1/1 and looking at how many are active at 8/1 and 222 would be picked up if you started your date filter at 2/1 instead of 1/1?

Comment: That is completely correct!  Basically all "active" policies at the point in time and of those, what percent are still active at the end.  It shouldn't include and policies were canceled before the pit, then reinstate after the pit or include any new business after the initial pit. Thank you again for your help. Your wisdom is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this usage of "pit".

Comment: Sorry PIT = Point In Time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do something like this:

```
Retention =
VAR StartDates =
    SUMMARIZE (
        ALLSELECTED ( PolicyLog ),
        PolicyLog[PolicyNum],
        "Start", MIN ( PolicyLog[StatusDate] )
    )
VAR Included =
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        FILTER ( StartDates, [Start] <= MIN ( Dates[Date] ) ),
        "Policies", PolicyLog[PolicyNum]
    )
VAR Filtered = FILTER ( PolicyLog, PolicyLog[PolicyNum] IN Included )

RETURN
    DIVIDE (
        SUMX ( Filtered, PolicyLog[Net] ),
        COUNTROWS ( SUMMARIZE ( Filtered, PolicyLog[PolicyNum] ) )
    )
```

First, you create a table, `StartDates`, that gives the earliest dates for each policy limited to the time frame you have selected. It would look something like this:

```
StartData = 

PolicyNum  Start
123        1/1/2018
222        2/1/2018
333        1/1/2018
444        1/1/2018
```

From there, we just want a list of which policies we want to include in the calculation. So we pick the ones that have a `Start` on the minimum selected date in the date slicer. We just want a list of the resulting policy numbers, so we just select that column.

```
Included =

Policies
123
333
444
```

From there we filter the whole `PolicyLog` table to just include these ones (`Filtered`).

Finally, we can add up the `Net` column for each of these selected policies and divide by the distinct count of them to get our retention percentage.

---

**Edit:** In response to your comment, I think you want to be a bit more selective with the `StartDate` variable. Instead of `MIN( PolicyLog[StatusDate] )`, try something more like this:

```
CALCULATE( MIN(PolicyLog[StatusDate]), PolicyLog[Status] IN {"N", "RN", "RI"} )
```

Comment: This is great!  I think it is really close, however there seems to be some issue.  I think it has to do with when a policy cancels then re-instates (but not sure yet).  I think the filtered var has to be where the sum of the net has to be =1. Otherwise the policynum may be in a cancelled state.  If that seems logical, can you give me a hint on how I would do that?  Would I create another variable or fit it in with the Include variable?  Thanks again for helping out Alexis.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Can you give an example with dates and its current and desired behavior?

Comment: I have the data in a data model in excel similar to the abridged data above. If using dates starting 3/31, policy 123 should not be "included " because it has been cancelled, but it does have a date less than 3/31.

Comment: Gotcha. I think you can just adjust the `StartDate` step a bit by only taking the min over certain statuses. Please see my edit.

Comment: Getting closer, but still not getting the results I was hoping.  I'm working through some test cases, and I'm thinking it has to do with fact some have multiple cancels and reinstatements on the same policy not sure yet.    I also seem to be having some sort of issue when filtering by policy attributes (territory, policy holder age, etc).  The end goal is to identify retention by policy attribute to identify what business is being lost.  If you have any suggestions, please send them my way. Otherwise I think I got some digging on my side to do.

Comment: I think I need to use the last status on or before the selected dates (by policy number) or the sum of all the values or before the selected dates (by policy number) as a column to get active status .  Of the ones that are "1" then use the last value in the range and sum the (current) status divided by the count of distinct policies  to get retention.  I'm having a problem sum of all the values or before the selected dates.  any good ideas?

Comment: So you're saying if you started at 1/2/2018, then you'd want to pick up 123, 333, and 444 since they are active?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Correct for the example above.  I've also been experimenting with re-arranging the transaction table includes the status of each policy at the end of the month, otherwise the it is possible that an annual policy may be in an active state, but not get included.  i.e  if an annual policy is new 12/31/2017 and the selected date range is 1/31/2018 to 6/30/2018 the policy will not get picked up unless it had any transactions.  Therefore I have the policy listed once for each month and a current state.

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get policies that are in an active state at the beginning of the filtered range to the end of the filtered range.  Something with first and last value function?  I spent a lot of time trying to do this at the column level, but I recently found out that columns don't get recalculated on the fly. In the end I need to get percent retention on related dimensions, such as territory, age, etc. Thanks again for your assistance.

Comment: I updated above with a close resemblance of what I am looking for